# Django. How to create model instance in test db using objects fabric?

Tags: python, django

I want to make my unit tests setUp function clear from repeating tons of model creation lines like 1) create user 2) now create employee with fk to this user and etc.
In order to do that I've made a simple factory of dummy objects but I might've done some mistakes or just misunderstood something. Here's a piece of factory (dummy_data is just a bunch of dicts):

```
from abc import ABC
from users.models import User
from employees.models import Employee
from .dummy_data import(
    user_data,
    employee_data,
)

class DummyObjectFactory(ABC):
    """Fabric representing dummy test objects"""

    def get_dummy_object(self):
        """Return dummy object"""

class DummyUser(DummyObjectFactory):

    def get_dummy_object(self) -> User:
        return User.objects.create_user(**user_data)

class DummyEmployee(DummyObjectFactory):

    def get_dummy_object(self) -> Employee:
        user = DummyUser().get_dummy_object()
        return Employee.objects.create(**employee_data, user=user)

dummy_factory = {
    "User": DummyUser().get_dummy_object(),
    "Employee": DummyEmployee().get_dummy_object(),
}
dummy_factory = dot_dict(dummy_factory)
```

Then I make a dot notaion dictionary of all kinds of fabrics for easy calling them buy dummy_factory.Name . My intetion was that I call fabric with the desired model name and it creates it's instance.
The problem is: when I call it in some test's setUp method like so `test_user = dummy_factory.User` it creates object in actual database but I want it to be in test database.

Example of test:

```
class TestEmployeesListView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.test_user = dummy_factory.User
        self.test_employee = dummy_factory.Employee
        self.client = Client()

    def test_listview_deny_anonymous_user(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('employees:employees-list'))
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/login/?next=/employees/')
```

Yes, I've searched for the solution and found Factory boy and Faker libraries, but I want to complete my fabric, make it work properly. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: How exactly are you using that in tests? Can you share? It's strange, that it would make objects in main database.

Comment: @NixonSparrow I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: You are not sharing `dummy_factory`. I have no idea, what is it and how it is created/imported.

Comment: @NixonSparrow Updated the question with dummy_factory. It is a dictionary with keys and values as ModelName: FactoryName().get_dummy_object()

Comment: And dot_dict is just a small library which makes it possible to access dict values with dot notaion.

Comment: The call to your `get_dummy_object` methods are directly present in your file. That means when the file is imported the code runs, the test context isn't setup yet when you import the file. You should instead wrap them in a function and call that function from your test code.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for hint, I wrapped them but still no luck.  What have I done wrong? > def dummy_factory(desired_dummy):

    factories={
        "User": DummyUser,
        "Employee": DummyEmployee,
    }

    return factories[desired_dummy]()

Comment: I would also recommend using a library to acess a dict by dot notation, sometimes it can be faster. For example [dotwiz](https://dotwiz.readthedocs.io/) is one I might suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it work. What I did was:

1. Added @abstractmethod decorator in the abstract class.
2. Every concrete factory methods must have a @classmethod decorator and recieve cls as an argument:

   class DummyUser(DummyObjectFactory):

   ```
    @classmethod
    def get_dummy_object(cls) -> User:
        return User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
   ```

It just work as intended: factory creates objects in test db. Thank you folks for participation.